# Convert Non-List Type to List Directly

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, integer

I have a list of items that I need to actually be a list of lists. All the conversion methods I have seen convert the non-list items to lists of individual characters `["12", "cat", 87]` to `[['1', '2'], ['c', 'a', 't'], ['8', '7']]` instead of `[['12'], ['cat'], [87]]`. The following works,

```
v_Data = ["12", "cat", 87]
for index, i in enumerate(v_Data):
    if type(i) != list:
        v_Data[index] = [i]
print(v_Data) ## [['12'], ['cat'], [87]]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `list-comprehension`:

```
v_Data = ["12", "cat", 87]

[v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for v in v_Data]
# [['12'], ['cat'], [87]]
```

Comment: Good answer. I was playing around with `isinstance` but could not get it to work. Your answer works, and points me in the right direction with `isinstance` in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do :

```
>>> a=["12", "cat", 87]
>>> b=[[i] for i in a]
>>> b
[['12'], ['cat'], [87]]
```

***EDIT*** :
if there is already list in your list :

```
>>> a=["12", "cat", 87, [23]]
>>> b=[[i] if type(i) is not list else i for i in a]
>>> b
[['12'], ['cat'], [87], [23]]
```

Comment: see Edit in my post !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
v_Data = ["12", "cat", 87]

new = [[x] for x in v_Data]
```

Similar to:

```
v_Data = ["12", "cat", 87]

new = []
for x in v_Data:
    new.append([x])
```